# Want a help in simple HTML

Tags: html

I've made a vertical menu for my webpage. I want that when i click on any item in the menu, the content open without loading other page. The previous div hides and other div comes on clicking on the menu. Can anyone help me here?

http://demo.tinywall.info/html5-history-api/menu2.php 
I need something like this, but with simple HTML and CSS. I also don't need to change URL, the url will be same. Only the hidden content shows up.
This is the website where i want to put this thing -> www.techstore.tk

Comment: Post JsFiddle please, or copy your code, we can't help you like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#btnLeft:active {
    ...
}
```

Then insert anything that you want to change in that.

Or if you want to have `jquery` in, you can do the following:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".category").click(function(){
        $(".filter").toggle("swing");
    });
});
</script>

    <div class="category">Select Me</div>
    <div class="filter">My hide able div</div>
```

**Speed**

- milliseconds - You can do any number to define how fast it it.
- "slow"
- "fast"

**Easing**

- "swing" - moves slower at the beginning/end, but faster in the middle
- "linear" - moves in a constant speed

Or, you can try a slide effect like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".categorie").click(function(){
        $("#.filter").slideToggle("slow"); // You can add any transition in place of "slow".
    });
});
```

**Callback functions**

A callback function is executed after the current effect is 100% finished. But you can call another function before the effect starts. Here are both examples:

**Callback** - Executes after the effect is finished:

```
$(".category").click(function(){
    $(".filter").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The effect just finished");
    });
});
```

Executes before the effect starts. Note: this is not called a callback:

```
$(".category").click(function(){
    $(".filter").hide(1000);
    alert("The effect will start after this message goes away");
});
```

Comment: This is the thing that I want, But how can I add some loading effects in this? http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/M3ZhV/ @Katherina

Comment: how can i add some loading effects in this? any small effect or simple transition is enough

Comment: If I answered your question, please hit the accept button. (It's the check mark right under the number of votes for this answer.) I don't understand what you mean for 2-3 tabs. Can you explain more?